# INT 13h, get status of last op

Tags: assembly, boot, 16-bit

I'm writing a bootloader for BIOS in 16-bit real mode, using qemu as my emulator.

I have some code that fails to read from my HD.  That's OK, but what actually bothers me is when I try to get the status code from that operation using the "Get Status of Last Drive Operation".

According to [this wikipedia resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D01h:_Get_Status_of_Last_Drive_Operation), I can simply set AH to 1, and set DL to my desired drive (which I've verified is 0x80).  Then, when I invoke `int 13h`, AL should have the status code in it.

However, when I do this, the carry flag gets set, indicating that my attempt to read the status itself failed.

Other that specifying the wrong drive, I don't see how it could possibly fail.

So my question is, *what are the ways this command (INT 13h, AH 01h) could possibly fail*?

Here's my code:

```
get_status:
    mov ah, 0x01    ; status fxn
    mov dl, 0x80    ; 0x80 is our drive
    int 0x13        ; call fxn

    jc print_status_failure
    jmp $

print_status_failure:
    mov ax, FAIL_MSG
    call print_string
    jmp $
```

Comment: And what do you get in `AL` and `AH`? Apparently bios versions differ in where they return the info. Also, the `CF` set may apply to the fact that the status itself isn't OK, not that the request itself failed.

Comment: As a suggestion, you may want to take a look at what BIOS is putting into the drive number.  I forget if it's in `DL` or `DH` on boot, but it is sometimes not what you expect.  This can lead to the error you are seeing because the drive is not actually 0x80.

Comment: Why not just check AH after Fn 0x02 returned CF set? You'll get the same result

Comment: @Jester: I thought that also; the wikipedia article is vague.  @DavidHoelzer `dl = 0x80` when I first start.  Also, I'm able to read so long as I don't grab more then 3 sectors at a time.  @AlexanderZhak: So, before I call 13h, `ah = 0x02` and `al = 0x05` (read 5 sectors).  After the read op,  `ax = 0x0C03`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, when I invoke int 13h, AL should have the status code in it.

BIOS function 01h for INT 13h only returns a result in the **AH** register. The carry flag is not defined and so you should never test for any *failure* after having invoked this function!

Comment: Awesome!  I'm getting consistent behavior when I check AH instead of AL. After getting 'media type not found', I realized that my problem was reading beyond the number of sectors on Qemu's virtual HD.  Thanks!

Comment: For future references, the Wikipedia error was corrected.